# How do I call this TypeScript method that has an optional argument?

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters

The VSCode [Position](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Position) class has two methods that look like this:

```
translate(lineDelta?: number, characterDelta?: number): Position
translate(change: {characterDelta: number, lineDelta: number}): Position
```

I want to call it supplying only a characterDelta. I tried doing this:

```
let endPos = startPos.translate(characterDelta: error.location.length);
```

However I get this error:

```
Cannot find name 'characterDelta'.
```

I figured the purpose of the `?` on the arguments for the first overload meant they were optional and I could just provide the one I needed. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method you don't name the parameter, but according to the signature you need to supply the first optional parameter as well, so it should be something like:

```
let lineDelta: number = ...
let endPos = startPos.translate(lineDelta, error.location.length);
```

Or:

```
let characterDelta: number = ...
let endPos = startPos.translate({
    characterDelta: characterDelta, 
    lineDelta : error.location.length
});
```

Optional parameters are maybe optional, but if you want to pass the 2nd optional parameter then you need to also pass the first one.
So these are valid (according to the signature):

```
startPos.translate();
startPos.translate(lineDelta);
startPos.translate(lineDelta, characterDelta);
```

Comment: So in this case, what is the point of the first argument being marked as optional? (Calling a translate method to do no translation is pointless, and even documented as just returning `this`) :-/

Comment: Good question, I have no idea, maybe who ever designed this api thought that maybe there are scenarios in which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

It expects an object with the **characterDelta** and **lineDelta** properties.

```
let endPos = startPos.translate({characterDelta: error.location.length, lineDelta: 5});
```

Comment: The second overload does, but I was trying to use the first one (`translate(lineDelta?: number, characterDelta?: number): Position`)